# How do I feed couchbase view output into another view?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Say that I have a set of documents of varying types that all contain a single date field. I am looking to get `max(date)` for documents of a given type. However, date only exists in each document once. Meaning that a single view will only be able to output max(date) for each document.

```
[{1,date},{1,date},{1,date},{2,date},{2,date}]
```

So theoretically if I was able to run an additional view on this output, I could easily get the output I need.

```
[{1,date},{2,date}]
```

I could accomplish this by querying the first view and creating a new document, which would then be used by the second view. Since now each document has multiple dates, the aggregate works.

However, this is not dynamic at all and adds a lot of overhead - basically defeating the purpose of switching from simple n1ql in the first place.

Is there any way to chain / nest / increment views in couchbase?

Comment: Why, may I ask, are you trying to do this with views? Selecting the maximum date from a set of documents of a particular type would be both easy and efficient in N1QL. `SELECT max(date) FROM testbucket WHERE type = 'mytype'` and `CREATE INDEX date_idx_mytype on testbucket(date) WHERE type = 'mytype'`

Comment: I want to display the data using ajax for paging @JohanLarson

Comment: I'm using n1ql right now and it works fine - but I basically have to get all the info into the UI at once and then page client-side.

Comment: I'll ping someone from our views team to advise. They're in India, so you might get an answer Monday morning.

Comment: Is the problem with N1QL that you want multiple results of different queries returned in a single request? Because N1QL can do that. You can glue together completely different queries using UNION ALL clauses, and the results of all of them will arrive together.

Comment: The problem was that N1QL doesn't support url parameters. That said I think I might be able to write something to insert them into the query. Honestly I thought that views would be the easiest way.

Comment: N1QL definitely supports url parameters. Here is an example that uses two parameters, $val1 and $val2. `curl 'http://localhost:8093/query/service?statement=select%20%24val1%20as%20this%2C%20%24val2%20as%20that&$val1=5&$val2=7'` The url-encoding is a bit of a mess, unfortunately. Here is the query unencoded: `select $val1 as this, $val2 as that`

Comment: Oh, very cool. @JohanLarson I will use this. Was there a wiki page explaining this? I didn't find any while I was doing research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jacob, you can do paging with N1QL:

> SELECT max(date)
> FROM testbucket
> WHERE type = 'mytype'
> GROUP BY grp
> LIMIT 10
> OFFSET 100

You could also define a view as follows:

> map:
> emit(doc.id, doc.date)
>
> reduce:
> _stats

The [built-in _stats reduce function](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/views/views-writing-stats.html) will emit a number of useful values including the maximum which may be what you're looking for.

You can also define a custom reduce function. More details appear here:
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/views/views-writing.html

*In general, N1QL approach should be preferred except for some niche cases that require Views map/reduce capability*. From the problem description, it should be possible to accomplish what you need via N1QL.